# Is it possible to get Timestamp in output template as DateTimeKind.Utc?

Tags: .net, serilog

Currently when I use `{Timestamp}` in an outputTemplate it appears to have been generated by `DateTime.Now` and therefore being of `DateTimeKind.Local` flavor since, when I give it an "o" specifier it produces output similar to `2016-02-12T09:51:34.4477761-08:00`

What I'd like to get instead for the above example is `2016-02-12T17:51:34.4477761Z`, which would have been produced had the `Timestamp` been of `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

**Update**

It looks like it is actually [DateTimeOffset that gets instantiated there](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/dev/src/Serilog/Core/Pipeline/Logger.cs#L134) so no `DateTimeKind` is in effect, rather it looks like underlying `DateTime` is always of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351892(v=vs.110).aspx) notes that there is some difference in behavior when formatting `DateTimeOffset` vs `DateTime`, specifically:

> "u" --  Converts the DateTimeOffset value to UTC and outputs it using the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ.

The conversion is exactly what I want but I also need fractions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears the limitation in `DateTimeOffset` formatting is going to thwart this.

An alternative (so long as the additional property doesn't bloat output somewhere else) is to add a Serilog `ILogEventEnricher` to the pipeline:

```
class UtcTimestampEnricher : ILogEventEnricher {
  public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory lepf) {
    logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(
      lepf.CreateProperty("UtcTimestamp", logEvent.Timestamp.UtcDateTime));
  }
}
```

You can then use `{UtcTimestamp:o}` in your output template to get the value you need.

Answer (score 1):

[*Serilog.Expressions*](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) now supports formatting `DateTimeOffset` as UTC without any additional enrichment:

```cs
    // dotnet add package serilog.expressions
    .WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
        "[{UtcDateTime(@t):o} {@l:u3}] {@m}\n{@x}",
        theme: TemplateTheme.Code))
```

Note that the timestamp property is now `@t`, not `Timestamp`.